# React Native Maps Directions: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps, map-directions

When I take out the origin property of the Directions component, it runs with no errors but doesn't show the direction. When I put it, for obvious reasons, I get this error.

```
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <MapView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        region={region}
        showsUserLocation
        loadingEnabled>
        <MapView.Marker coordinate={region} />
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{latitude: -9.645601, longitude: -35.734108}}
        />
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={{latitude: -9.64561693, longitude: -35.73592044}}
          destination={{latitude: -9.645601, longitude: -35.734108}}
          apikey={'AIzaSyBVFhY3cURPTbAoOnkyAeijkAt2kqRJ2iY'}
          strokeWidth={3}
          strokeColor="#333"
        />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the error for it?

Comment: Hi @GauravRoy, I got the fix for it as I had opened an issue here: https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions/issues/130

Comment: @CarlosSudsilowsky Can you please post the answer to your question and accept the answer. This helps in cases where links to answers outside of stack overflow stop working but others face the same issue. Thank you :)

Comment: @CarlosSudsilowsky .. man you saved my ass...